# Mysql Select count with conditional statement

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I was instructed to make a query that counts a column if the value is greater than zero and the other one is equal to zero and greater than zero. I tried to use `CASE` for mysql but it does not work. Can anyone tell me what did I miss? Here is what I tried

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN aci.approved > 0) as approved, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN aci.approved == 0 AND aci.pending > 0) as pending 
from `admin_case_info` as `aci` 
inner join `users_mws` on `users_mws`.`id` = `aci`.`users_mws_id` 
inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `users_mws`.`user_id` 
where `users`.`status` not in ('Dumped','Dumped2') 
and `aci`.`case_type` = 'INBOUND_SHIPMENT'
```

The exception i got is

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') as approved,
COUNT(CASE WHEN aci.approved == 0 AND aci.pending > 0) as pendi' at line 2
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  It also makes no sense to select `COUNT` over the entire table and also use `LIMIT 10`.  Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: Ohh sorry. I add limit for testing. Sorry, please disregard the limit sir @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may sum boolean expressions, which is close to the syntax you were attempting:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(aci.approved > 0) AS approved,
    SUM(aci.approved = 0 AND aci.pending > 0) AS pending
FROM admin_case_info AS aci
INNER JOIN users_mws ON users_mws.id = aci.users_mws_id
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = users_mws.user_id
WHERE users.status NOT IN ('Dumped', 'Dumped2') AND aci.case_type = 'INBOUND_SHIPMENT';
```

Comment: Is it the same as count sir? Since I was trying to count the columns depending on the condition

Comment: Answer: Yes, the above logic will count the number of times the boolean expression be true (true evaluates to 1 and false evaluates to 0).  Try the code yourself.

Comment: Tried to use it but it gets me an ```You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 0 AND aci.pending > 0) AS pending
FROM admin_case_info AS aci
INNER JOIN use' at line 3```

Comment: `SUM(aci.approved = 0 ...)` <-- _don't_ use `==` for equality, just use `=`

Answer (score 1):

your forgot to end case function

(CASE
WHEN  your condition THEN result1
WHEN  your condition THEN result2
ELSE result
END);

Comment: can you set an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
customerName, 
orderCount,
CASE orderCount
    WHEN 1 THEN 'One-time Customer'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Repeated Customer'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Frequent Customer'
    ELSE 'Loyal Customer'
end customerType
```

FROM
cte
ORDER BY customerName;